# iOS Simulator gives 'You dont have permission error'

Tags: macos, permission, xcode-simulator

I am currently on macOS Monterey 12.2 and have started an iPhone 12 iOS 15.0 simulator. On this simulator, if I drop files from desktop or a folder inside desktop, I get an error saying, 'The file could not be opened because you don't have the permission to view it'.

However, if this files is moved to some folder inside ~/Builds/SampleFiles/*, the drag and drop copies the files to the simulator. Is something specific needed to be done to provide such an access to the simulator ? I can see that Simulator has 'Full Disk Access' under 'Security and Privacy'.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and what seemed to work is to first to drop the files into the Xcode project manager and then drag and drop it from there to the simulator. I am using Xcode 13.3 on macOS Monterey 12.2.1. It worked for .xml and .txt files